How do I divide a matrix into chunks, per row, and allocate each chunk to a process?
So I have been trying to divide my matrix into chunks of rows and allocating them to processes(using
pool
from multiprocessing)
For example, what I have done so far:
parser.add_argument("-p","--process",type = int, required= False,default = 1
processes = args.process(taking in the amount of processes)
rows_per_process = n / (processes)
remaining rows = n % (processes)

However, I am confused as to where to go from here. I am trying to perform this strictly using base python and no external libraries.
